# Multi Join Tsql Coalesce Inefficient Code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, pivot, coalesce

Need Help making code more efficient.

I have the following select (which will become an update statement) and right now I have to have 8 joins of exactly the same data. I tried a few things and failed but maybe the collective wisdom here will have some insight as to how to make it more efficient.

I have the following tables

```
#temp_data 
customer    season  id      percent
1           2016    835     35.93000    
1           2016    836     31.82000    
1           2016    837     11.88000    
1           2016    841     5.09000 
1           2016    839     15.28000    
1           2017    836     31.40000
1           2017    837     11.45000    
1           2017    839     14.04000    
1           2017    841     6.40000 
1           2017    835     36.70000
```

and

```
lt_program_data

customer season     value_835   value_836   value_837   value_838   value_839   value_840   value_841   value_842
1       2016        35.93000    31.82000    11.88000    NULL        15.28000    NULL        5.09000     NULL
1       2017        36.70000    31.40000    11.45000    NULL        14.04000    NULL        6.40000     NULL
1       2018        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
1       2019        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

What is happening, is that we match the two tables on season/customer/id values. In the scenarios where no value exist in the #temp_data table we use max value that exists. I was able to sort out the code to get it working. However, its large and ugly and not terribly efficient.

I either have to have 8 update statements where i explicitly state each id value (835, 836, etc). Or one large statement with 8 Joins on practically the same thing. Any advice on how to update the below for improved efficiency would be great.

As you can see the below is really the repetition of the exact same thing over and over again. While i understand the select part may require the 8 separate statements, is there a way to eliminate the 8 left outer joins to be one only.

Code:

```
select      a.customer, 
            fyear,
            value_835 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 835),    
                                        c1.[percent] ),

            value_836 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 836),    
                                        c2.[percent] ),

            value_837 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 837),    
                                        c3.[percent] ),

            value_838 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 838),    
                                        c4.[percent] ),

            value_839 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 839),    
                                        c5.[percent] ),

            value_840 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 840),    
                                        c6.[percent] ),

            value_841 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 841),    
                                        c7.[percent] ),

            value_842 = coalesce (( select [percent] from #temp_data d where d.season = a.fyear and d.customer = a.customer and d.id = 842),    
                                        c8.[percent] )
from        #lt_program_data a
left outer join (   --835
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent] 
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 835
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c1 on        a.customer = c1.customer 

left outer join (   --836
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 836
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c2 on        a.customer = c2.customer 

left outer join (   --837
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 837
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c3 on        a.customer = c3.customer 

left outer join (   --838
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 838
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c4 on        a.customer = c4.customer 

left outer join (   --839
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 839
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c5 on        a.customer = c5.customer 

left outer join (   --840
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 840
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c6 on        a.customer = c6.customer 


left outer join (   --841
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 841
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c7 on        a.customer = c7.customer 


left outer join (   --842
                    select a.customer, a.id, a.[percent]
                    from    #temp_data a
                    join    (   select z.customer, id, season =  max(z.season)
                                from    #temp_data z 
                                where   id = 842
                                group by z.customer, id 
                            )   b on a.customer = b.customer and a.season = b.season  and a.id = b.id 
                )  c8 on        a.customer = c8.customer
```

This is the sample output at the end.

```
customer    fyear   value_835   value_836   value_837   value_838   value_839   value_840   value_841   value_842
1           2016    35.93000    31.82000    11.88000    NULL        15.28000    NULL        5.09000     NULL
1           2017    36.70000    31.40000    11.45000    NULL        14.04000    NULL        6.40000     NULL
1           2018    36.70000    31.40000    11.45000    NULL        14.04000    NULL        6.40000     NULL
1           2019    36.70000    31.40000    11.45000    NULL        14.04000    NULL        6.40000     NULL
```

Comment: looks like you can use `UNPIVOT` to normalize your second table and make the query simpler. Not sure it will be more efficient though.

Comment: @YossiVainshtein I don't much about `UNPIVOT` I'll need to do more digging. I mean the code runs pretty quickly (under 2 seconds for a pretty substantial table) but it looks ugly and I think it could work better. So i'm open to all/any suggestions.

Comment: wait, I don't understand, isn't the data in the 2 tables exactly the same?

Comment: anyway, you can look at this sqlfiddle, it might help you 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7b35f/2

Comment: @YossiVainshtein I'm looking at the code shared. The sample is the same, but there is a lot more data in the lt_ table the values are stored in the #temp but are required in the lt_data table

Comment: so you want to find rows which appear in `#temp_data` but not `lt_program_data `?

Comment: #temp_data will have data for a given customer for a given year, but not all years. For example they'll have 2016, but not 17 or 18 yet. What users want to see in those cases is the 2016 data for the 17 and 18 years. Basically where data exists match it out exactly where it doesn't use the last existing (max existing) numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that wrapping my logical query blocks in a CTE helps me think more clearly about it. Here's one that `pivots` #temp_data instead of `unpivot`-ing lt_program_data.
If I understood you correctly, you should be able to <s>`left outer join`</s> `cross apply` with LatestData to get what you need.

```
;with LatestData as (
    select Customer, Season, [835],[836],[837],[838],[839],[840],[841],[842] from 
    (select Customer, Season, [percent], id from temp_data td) as TempSource
    pivot 
    ( sum([percent]) for id in ([835],[836],[837],[838],[839],[840],[841],[842])) as TempPivoted
    )

 select a.customer,
    a.season,
    value_835 = coalesce(a.value_835, latest.[835]),
    value_836 = coalesce(a.value_836, latest.[836]),
    value_837 = coalesce(a.value_837, latest.[837]),
    value_838 = coalesce(a.value_838, latest.[838]),
    value_839 = coalesce(a.value_839, latest.[839]),
    value_840 = coalesce(a.value_840, latest.[840]),
    value_841 = coalesce(a.value_841, latest.[841]),
    value_842 = coalesce(a.value_842, latest.[842])
from lt_program_data a
cross apply (select top 1 * from LatestData where LatestData.customer = a.customer and latestdata.season <= a.season order by season desc) as latest
```

Comment: Oh, one more thing: if you're familiar with CTEs please ignore my elaboration, but if they are unfamiliar to you please be aware that they are "immediate, single-use" only, in that the CTE (LatestData, in this case) can only be referenced by the command immediately following its declaration. In short, `select * from LatestData` must be replaced with your final select that joins on it.

Comment: I am familiar with CTEs, thank you for this i will check it out.

Comment: how do i transform this into what i need ... I get pivoting the data, but i don't know what would happen next?

Comment: I've updated the sample in my answer with what I was thinking.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Did that give you what you were looking for?